# Cell mask format

Tags: excel, vba, mask

I'm trying to develop a mask to my cells that as requirement it needs to be only text or numerals.

I also have a clean button to reset my respective cells. That's my problem. My mask checking macro is working good but if when i use my clean button and they get empty, the same checking macro say that blank isn't accepted.

Following my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then


        If Not IsNumeric(Range("C5").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If

        Range("C5").Value = "" & Format(Range("C5").Value, "")
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7")) Is Nothing Then
        'apaga se nao for o numero
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("C7").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If

        Range("C7").Value = "'" & Format(Range("C7").Value, "")
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I9")) Is Nothing Then
         'apaga se nao for o numero
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("I9").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If


    End If

     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I11")) Is Nothing Then
         'apaga se nao for o numero
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("I11").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If


    End If


     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I13")) Is Nothing Then
         'apaga se nao for o numero
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("I13").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If


    End If


     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E15")) Is Nothing Then
         'apaga se nao for o numero
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("E15").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
        End If
            End If

If Not Application.IsText(Worksheets("Formulário").Range("C9")) Then
MsgBox "Valor inválido."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo LetsContinue
End If



LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = Truea
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Function IsAlpha(str As String) As Boolean
Dim c As String
Dim I As Integer

    For I = 1 To Len(str)
        c = Mid(str, I, 1)

        Select Case Asc(c)

            Case 32, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                IsAlpha = True
            Case Else
                IsAlpha = False
        End Select

        If Not IsAlpha Then Exit For
    Next I
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following routine instead, using VBA-style regular expressions to test for your rules:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Union(Range("C5"),Range("C7"), Range("I9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Target.Value Like "[a-zA-Z0-9]+" Then
    MsgBox "Valor inválido."
    Application.Undo
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Then in your macro for "cleaning" the cells, make sure that you use `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end, this stops events from firing, which will mean that the above code isn't run when your macro changes the value of the cell.